# Multi Step Form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multi-step, wicked-gem

I am making a multi step form in Rails 3.2 , the problem being i get to see the fields  generated in the sign-up process but i am unable to update them in the second step . I have looked into Ryan Bates's video but mine is a bit complex . The basic devise fields work fine but those that i added through migrations show nil value . I have defined those fields in attr_accessible in my model as well. Following is my controller code to save the data in second step :-

```
class Users::AfterSignupController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :step_1

   def show
    @user = current_user
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    render_wizard
  end

  private

  def redirect_to_finish_wizard
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up."
  end


end
```

Looking forward to helpful suggestions , as the code suggests i have used Wicked gem for the multi step implementation . But if anyone can guide me to do it in normal rails way then i am up for it too . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere where you are saving the user in the update step. As stated in the Wizard  documentation if you pass an object to `render_wizard` it will move to the next wizard step if the object saves or remain at the current step if it fails. So something like this should perform the save

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  render_wizard @user
end
```